# putty and log viewer

Tags: putty

We are developing a java web application. We'll  be  deploying the application in the linux server. To connect to the server we're using the putty tool.

For the local testing of the application we use our local host and use a log viewer to see the logs.

Is there are any tool to view the log files in the remote machine by using the tunneling methods in putty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, assuming I wanted to see a log file in /var/log.

Sample:
On Remote Server, going to tunnel to, using python:

> cd /var/log

In that directory,

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080

Configure Putty [ Remote-Host-IP: Remote-Port ] x.x.x.x:8080.
SSH in, Thereafter in your browser you can just type:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

All log files fully accessible.

Putting this into code is a little harder. I would suggest getting an SSH library (plenty around), or writing a remote web service which tails logs and spits out most recent updates etc. Perhaps you could issue get requests even to 'tail -n x' (x - being the number of most recent records you would want to see.

Addendum: 
[How to Configure Tunneling](https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/) to watch logs from remote machines in real time (log4j and JDK logging). It supports SFTP and Samba. On development environment I'm using [log4j SocketHubAppender](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/SocketHubAppender).

It's also worth to see following [demo on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESCa-X8l4OE)